# It is not clear the regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Why is this a regular expression gives the following result: "abcdcdcd"?

```
'abcdcdcdlorem'.match(/(ab|cd)+|ef/); // ["abcdcdcd", "cd"]
```

Alternatively processed from left to right until a match is found. When a match is found on the left-right alternative is ignored, even if it is possible to achieve the "best" match.

Comment: Your parentheses capture only `ab` or `cd`. The "best match" is `"abcdcdcd"`

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: @Kstro21, I expected ab

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov how would it be `ab` if there are still `cdcdcd` characters to match?

Comment: @zerkms, Quote from the book: Alternatively processed from left to right until a match is found. When a match is found on the left-right alternative is ignored, even if it is possible to achieve the "best" match.

Comment: @zerkms, `'ab'.match(/a|ab/); // a`

Why, then, this expression is only a?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov `'ab'.match(/a|ab/); // a` because it matched already - why to match something else? Not sure what book you're referring to btw. Compare with `'ab'.match(/(a|b)+/);`

Comment: @zerkms, if you add + `'ab'.match ((/ a | ab /) +);` That is why he does not catch and b?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov because `a` has already matched. You asked `a` **or** `ab`. It literally means you're satisfied if you get either. `a` perfectly fits your request so it is returned.

Comment: @zerkms, there is still +, which stands for greed

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov it has nothing to do with greediness `'ab'.match ((/ a | ab /) +)` --- you match `a` with `a`, then `b` is left which cannot be matched with anything. So it stops and returns what has been captured.

Comment: @zerkms, 'abcdcdcdlorem'.match(/(ab|cd)+|ef/); Why then here + work? And it does not return ab?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov it matches `ab` with `ab`, so `cdcdcdlorem` left. Then it matches `cd` with `cd`, then `cdcdlorem` left, and so on. So it matches a part of the string, chops it and never returns back.

Comment: @zerkms, I did not understand anything specific. Well, I will understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In alternations, the expressions to the left have priority. It's a common trap for beginners to think that `a|ab|abc|abcd` will match `abcd`.

It won't, it only matches `a` because that satisfies the alternation
with 
priority given to the item on the left.

However, if the alternations are within a grouped construct, the engine   considers the quantification of the constructs surrounding the group.

Even still, within a group, with a quantifier of 1 or more times,
this `(a|ab|abc|abcd)+` still will only match `a` in `abcd` then stop.

*So, don't fall into that trap !!*

Comment: `'abcdcdcdlorem'.match(/(ab|cd)+|ef/);`

@sln, why not stop here on ab? ab or cd {1,}.

Comment: You tell me, why not stop here on ab? `'abcdcdcdlorem'.match(/ab|cd/);` I guess because `/(ab|cd)+/` is a while loop.

Comment: Because either ab or cd

Answer (score 1):

The `+` in the regular expression instructs it to continue to keep finding instances of `ab|cd`, so it finds `ab` once, and `cd` three more times.